# Can I play the same game on two different Xbox One consoles with only one Xbox Live Gold account?

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network

If I have two Xbox One consoles, but only one Xbox Live Gold account, can I play the same game on the same profile at the same time? Or do I need two profiles + two Xbox Live Gold accounts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot play on one Xbox Live on two Xbox One's simultaneously.

> You can only sign in to one Xbox One or one Xbox 360 console at a time. If you try to sign in on a second console, you'll be asked whether you want to sign out from the first console. If you respond yes, your account will be immediately signed out of the first Xbox One console.

[Xbox Support - Concurrent SignIn](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/my-account/security/concurrent-signin)

Answer (score 8):

You cannot play on 1 profile with 2 different xboxes at the same time, so you'll need 2 profiles with Gold.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two xboxs, you can set up one of those as your home xbox. On that particular one, make a new profile. Then, you'll be able to play on that one with the new profile and it will have gold.

Then sign into the other xbox with your main account, and it will work fine.

At least, that's as far as I understand it; I could be wrong as I haven't actually tried this out.

Comment: Although that would allow you to not have to purchase two copies of the game, it does not let you play multiple characters from the same account. The rules that prevent multiple logins on the same profile still apply, even if it's a home Xbox.

Comment: That's why I suggested making a new profile, with silver status. In theory, it should allow you to play as if you had a gold account if the gold account marks that system as home.

Comment: But if you are signed in to the secondary account, you aren't signed into the primary one, right? So you can't access characters that are on the primary account?

Comment: I don't think the question was about accessing multiple characters on the same primary account, but no you wouldn't be able to access characters on the primary account when signed into the secondary account. However, I presume you could trade between the two if both are logged into the same server/party.